# sudo apt-get -f install error

Tags: package-management

I'm a ubuntu noob and whenever I try to download something there a bunch of unmet wine dependencies, I go to run sudo apt-get -f install and get this.

```
bailey@bailey-FQ565AA-ABA-a6700f:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libkresources4 libqrencode3 libkprintutils4 libqscintilla2-8 libsm-dev
  libkldap4 ttf-umefont libice-dev libkcalcore4 libprison0
  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libkholidays4 libknewstuff2-4 libpthread-stubs0
  linux-headers-3.2.0-55 python-qscintilla2 linux-headers-3.2.0-55-generic
  nvidia-settings-304-updates libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1
  mysql-server-core-5.5 wine-mono0.0.8 akonadi-backend-mysql x11proto-kb-dev
  libkmbox4 xtrans-dev libkcalutils4 akonadi-server libmicroblog4
  wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386
  x11proto-input-dev libkabc4 mysql-client-core-5.5 libxt-dev
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic libkcal4 libkalarmcal2 libakonadi-calendar4
  language-pack-kde-en linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libkimap4 libxau-dev
  kde-l10n-engb libmailtransport4 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 openjdk-7-jre-lib
  libkpimtextedit4 libkmime4 kdepimlibs-kio-plugins ttf-unfonts-core
  thunderbird-globalmenu xorg-sgml-doctools libakonadi-kabc4 libx11-dev
  libkpimidentities4 libkpimutils4 libx11-doc libxcb1-dev
  language-pack-kde-en-base kdepim-runtime libakonadi-kcal4 x11proto-core-dev
  libakonadi-notes4 libxdmcp-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libakonadi-contact4
  libakonadi-kde4 python-kde4 libdmtx0a
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386:i386
Suggested packages:
  dosbox:any
Recommended packages:
  wine-gecko2.24
The following packages will be upgraded:
  wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386:i386
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 305 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/58.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 7,751 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.7:
 wine1.7 depends on wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.15-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package wine1.7-i386 is not installed.
  Version of wine1.7-i386:i386 on system is 1:1.7.16-0ubuntu1.
dpkg: error processing wine1.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.7-i386:i386:
 wine1.7-i386:i386 depends on wine1.7:any (= 1:1.7.16-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of wine1.7 on system is 1:1.7.15-0ubuntu1.
dpkg: error processing wine1.7-i386:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.7-amd64:
 wine1.7-amd64 depends on wine1.7:any (= 1:1.7.15-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package wine1.7 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing wine1.7-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 wine1.7
 wine1.7-i386:i386
 wine1.7-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Would you mind reinstalling Wine? Btw. PlayOnLinux is a frontend for wine, which is much more easy to work with.

Comment: I would reinstall wine but again I'm an ubuntu noob I hardly know how to do anything in terminal.

Comment: Do you have anything installed in wine you need?

Comment: Anything installed in wine I need I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing everything related to WineHQ:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine*
```

Now run a clean-up to get rid of all remaining stuff (Btw. Where does all the KDE stuff come from?). This will remove any program that was installed as a dependency, which isn't needed any more.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now run `sudo apt-get install -f`, in case there still are broken packages.

Install PlayOnLinux:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Handle everyting Wine-related using PlayOnLinux. It has a virtual drive manager, which creates a wine prefix for each program you install.

Comment: I'm still getting errors when running sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: What errors are shown?